# Exploded artifact can't be uploaded with glassfish

Tags: java, intellij-idea, deployment, glassfish, war

I try to deploy my project to remote glassfish server where hosted in AWS, I am able to connect to the remote server via intellij remote glassfish server, but when I tried to deploy the artifact it gives me an error saying "Exploded artifact can't be uploaded with glassfish"

[image]

Comment: Are you using elastic beanstalk with pre configured docker? Not sure you can do deployment directly, you have to do it either through the AWS CLI or the website.

Answer (score 2):

You have to deploy your application packaged as WAR or EAR, because GlassFish does not support deploying exploded archives remotely (only when running on the same machine as Idea).

More info in an old Idea bug report: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-63345